# Any ways to filter Azure subscriptions by tags with az cli?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18463:

We have a lot of subcriptions and I need to filter them via tag.

The only way I found it was to list all the subs (`az account list`) and then call `az tag list  --resource-id /subscriptions/${subid} -o json`.

This is painfully slow as it takes about 30 seconds to execute on 88 subs.

I looked into `az resource list` but that always points to a single sub and can be used to filter resources inside the sub.

Any better way of doing this?

We are going to end up calling the `az tag list` api a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Azure Resource Graph** can help here as it is engineered for fast responses!

With the `resource-graph` extension for Azure CLI, you can craft a command to query Subscriptions and their tags as under:

```
az graph query -q "resourcecontainers | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project id, name, subscriptionId, tags"
```

and work through the result as needed.

Reference: [az graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/graph?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: yes - this worked for me, it's a pretty fast solution to the problem.